# Convert first character of each word capital in input in oracle form

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am using a text field input for the Student Name input. How can i convert the first character of each word capital automatically ?

Comment: [initcap](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions065.htm) could help

Comment: What do you mean by a word? Should `o'brien` be `O'brien` or `O'Brien`? Is `mary-anne` converted to `Mary-anne` or `Mary-Anne`? Or even `mcdonald` - should it not be `McDonald` and not `Mcdonald`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions065.htm) :

> INITCAP returns char, with the first letter of each word in uppercase,
>   all other letters in lowercase. Words are delimited by white space or
>   characters that are not alphanumeric.

```
SELECT INITCAP('the soap') "Capitals" FROM DUAL; 

Capitals
---------
The Soap
```

Of course, `INITCAP` has its own rules, so you need to check if its behaviour fits your need; using MT0's examples:

```
SQL> with test(text) as (
  2  select 'o''brien' from dual union all
  3  select 'mary-anne' from dual union all
  4  select 'mcdonald' from dual
  5  )
  6  select text, initcap(text)
  7  from test;

TEXT      INITCAP(T
--------- ---------
o'brien   O'Brien
mary-anne Mary-Anne
mcdonald  Mcdonald
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, INITCAP returns the same data type as its input (which must be of "character type" - CHAR, VARCHAR2, CLOB, etc.)